# Count with ActiveRecordObject.select

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to do something like this

```
User.select("users.id, count(whatever) as test")
```

But rails return only the User.id without the count. 
I can't use something like

```
User.count(whatever)
```

Because I use this select in a very complex SQL query. Is it possible to get the count value with select helper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the following query returns `User.id`?  Doesn't it throw an error saying "column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group by clause":

```
User.select("users.id, count(whatever) as test")
```

Because you are using `count` you should also use `group` method as following:

```
User.select("users.id, count(whatever) as test").group("users.id, whatever")
```

Then your resultant array will contain `users.id` and `count(whatever)`.